# What is algorithm name for "Count Points in Polygon" using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, algorithm

I want to count points in polygon, using PyQGIS. When I check the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html?highlight=count%20points%20polygon#count-points-in-polygon), I find the description of the `{parameter_dictionary}`, but not the algorithm name which must also be provided.

What is the name of the algorithm which I have to write in here `processing.run("algorithm_id", {parameter_dictionary})`?

Comment: Note that you can find that in the "testing" version of the docs: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#id6, which is the most up-to-date one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is `"native:countpointsinpolygon"`.

I usually execute the tools manually in QGIS then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to copy paste the syntax to use in PyQGIS.

Comment: Wonderful approach with Ctrl+Alt+H !

Comment: That has also been my go-to approach for quite some time. It really cuts down on visits to the docs, and a good entryway to scripting with PyQGIS. :)

Answer (score 7):

In case you do not know a name or id, you can use:

```py
searchstring = 'count' # to get all algorithms just leave this empty
for alg in QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithms():
    if searchstring in alg.id(): 
        print(alg.id())
```

to search for it. In your case its `native:countpointsinpolygon`

Comment: A smart solution when you know what to look for, but what if there are many algorithms that match similar name patterns.

Comment: Usually it should be clear by the id which one to choose. If there are several identical, you can identify them by the provider name. Thats just like when searching for a tool in processing toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, its documentation is here for the latest QGIS version, otherwise replace the word `testing` by, e.g. `3.16`:

https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#count-points-in-polygon